# Can't create a new Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

On my Windows 7 Pro PC, I installed Windows Virtual PC so that I could install Windows XP Mode, which I did. So now in the Windows Virtual PC directory there's no option to install a separate virtual PC. I've already tried "Manage Windows Virtual PC." Clicking on it brings up the directory containing Windows XP Mode, there's nothing else in that directory. I'm trying to install a Linux Virtual Machine and I don't want to use VMWare. Any suggestions?

[my Windows 7 Start Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWBc0.jpg)

Comment: Use VirtualBox instead.  You will be unable to accomplish what you want with Virtual-PC

Comment: AT Ramhound. If you know why then you should state why. e.g. maybe the file is formatted to virtualbox. and incompatible with vmware or virtual pc.. or both.   You should state your knowledge as to those cases, which covers the Why to your statement.  Generously sharing your knowledge rather than just issuing people instructions. and keeping the whys to yourself.

Comment: The VirtualBox website says, "VirtualBox is a general-purpose full virtualizer for x86 hardware." I have a 64-bit processor, I should have said that in my question. I'm going to go with VMWare and be done with this. I'm not going to spend the time looking for an older version of Microsoft Virtual PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want to do, you'll need to find an earlier version of Virtual-PC.

To be able to install Linux, or any other OS as a Virtual Machine, then you might want to try Virtual Box. It will have the capability of doing what you are looking for.